# Using Session variable for loop in php (3php script) with form checkbox for Excel sheet

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
session_start(); 
 // $filename = "Report_" . date('MmDY') . ".xls";
 // header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
 // header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");  
 // header("Pragma: no-cache");
 // header("Expires: 0");

include ('../connection.php');
include ('../libchart/classes/libchart.php');

$calendarDate1 = $_SESSION['dateCalendarONE'];
$calendarDate2 = $_SESSION['dateCalendarTWO'];  
$inputValue = $_SESSION['menuInputVALUE'];

   $sql = ("
SELECT *
FROM `tally`, `category`
WHERE tally.catid = category.catid AND
date BETWEEN '" . $calendarDate1 . "' AND '" . $calendarDate2 . "'
        AND CATLABEL='" . $inputValue . "'
GROUP BY `catlabel`
");
 $rec = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($rec);

//loop count
for($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name($rec,$i)."\t";
}
//Oraganize information on the database.
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rec))
{

    $line = '';
    foreach($row as $brotocol)
    {                                            
        if((!isset($brotocol)) || ($brotocol == ""))
        {
            $brotocol = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $brotocol = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $brotocol );
            $brotocol = '"' . $brotocol . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $brotocol;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}

$data = str_replace("\r" , "" , $data);

if ($data == "")
{
    $data = "\n BROTOCOL_ERROR: contact support!!!\n";                        
}

print "$header\n$data";
?>
```

When the session variable is passed, the exporting for excel is not looping through the and only reading 1 row. but When the sql statement is hard-coded in, it loops through as many rows as needed. Is the error with the loop alogrithm? or do I have to add another while loop in the code?

Comment: Have you `var_dump($sql)` to see the actual SQL query?

Comment: var_dump of $sql is NULL

Comment: Then you're assigning it the wrong way. Try without the parenthesis.

Comment: Nope, still a empty statement for the SQL. The Session variables are in there when I'm doing a echo of the variables.  The query is running  in the loop.     STATEMENT: 
tid sid uid date time catid CATID CatLabel Active  "376" "1" "1" "2012-10-17" "22:09:57" "2" "2" "Reference" "1" 
calendar1 : 2012-10-15 
calendar2: 2012-10-21
NULL

Comment: Ah nevermind, i solved the issue i was having, such a newbie mistake. =( i defined the session variable.